# How to calculate number of working days per week, between two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate number of working days per week between two dates.

Is there a way to build a formula in Excel to help with this?

[image: Formula Inputs]

I couldn't find any existing formulas in the forums to work this out.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text and not as image

Comment: Try using : `=LET(x, NETWORKDAYS(MAX(D$1,$B2),MIN(D$1+6,$C2)), IF(x<0,"",x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you would need either `NETWORKDAYS()` or `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` function to get the workdays between two dates, however if I am not wrong and understood correctly, then this is what you might be looking for:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, NETWORKDAYS(MAX(D$1,$B2),MIN(D$1+6,$C2)), IF(x<0,"",x))
```

---

**Note:** Both the `NETWORKDAYS()` & `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()` have a optional parameters for `[holidays]` but the latter one has an additional parameter for `[weekend]` which helps to customize the `workdays` & `weekends`. Read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28)**. In the above formula, the default weekends are `Saturdays` & `Sundays`.

---

Or, Using `MAKEARRAY()` --> `LAMBDA()` helper function to spill with one single dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B2:C5),COLUMNS(D1:G1),LAMBDA(r,c,
  LET(x, INDEX(D1:G1,,c), z, NETWORKDAYS(MAX(x,INDEX(B2:C5,r,1)),MIN(x+6,INDEX(B2:C5,r,2))),
  IF(z<0,"",z))))
```

---

Another alternative way, since number of workdays are needed per week, hence we can default take `5` as the max here, and use `SEQUENCE()` function instead of `NETWORKDAYS()` though its for fun, ethically i wont suggest, still

[image]

---

```
=LET(α,SEQUENCE(5,,D$1),SUM(($B2<=α)*($C2>=α)))
```

---

Or, Single dynamic array formula using `MAKEARRAY()`

```
=LET(
     α, D1:G1,
     φ, B2:C5,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(φ),COLUMNS(α),LAMBDA(r,c,
     LET(δ, SEQUENCE(5,,INDEX(α,,c)), σ, SUM((INDEX(φ,r,1)<=δ)*(INDEX(φ,r,2)>=δ)), 
     IF(σ,σ,"")))))
```

---

**Note:** The above formulas using `SEQUENCE()` dont have the `weekend` or `workday` customization like the `NETWORKDAYS()` hence its best you the first methods outlined.

---

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying out `NETWORKDAYS(start_date, end_date, [holidays])`. This function automatically excludes weekends (Saturday and Sunday) and can also exclude a list of specific holidays if provided.

- start_date: The start date of the period.
- end_date: The end date of the period.
- [holidays]: (Optional) A list of dates that should be excluded from the working day count, in addition to weekends.

In your example data `NETWORKDAYS(B2, C2)` would give the number of days between 12/18/23 and 12/29/23, excluding weekends.

See more docs [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not just looking to calculate the total number of working days between two dates, but the total number of working dates in a given week between two dates. Example: for project 0001A, the 12/18 column should show 5 days and the 12/25 column should show 5 days (not counting the 12/25 holiday. Is there a formula that would help me calculate this?